# Video quality problem with Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video, gpu

I have a GTX 1060 6GB GPU on my desktop connected to a 4K monitor. There is no image quality or resolution error, but when there is fast movement in a video, the image becomes pixelated.

I installed the driver and CUDA toolkit 10.1 from the official website.

With a Radeon GPU on the same machine, the video plays smoothly with crisp images.

Do you have any hint what can be the source of this problem?

```
nvidia-smi
Mon Apr  1 15:17:38 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.39       Driver Version: 418.39       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  On   | 00000000:42:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P0    28W / 120W |   1957MiB /  6077MiB |     25%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1560      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           587MiB |
|    0      1782      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         529MiB |
|    0     59194      G   ...quest-channel-token=6090805687932963293   557MiB |
|    0    101293      G   ...equest-channel-token=272009698120777591   280MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean by fast movement exactly? When you tested the RADEON video card, did you use the same monitor? What's the monitor model?

Comment: Latest version of the driver is 418.56, try that.  https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/145182

Comment: @ by fast movement, I mean when an object is moving in the video like a racing car. Yes, everything was the same when comparing two GPUs. And the monitor is ASUS PB287Q 28 Inch 4K.

Comment: Details regarding the video transcoding parameters in use for the video might be informative. You can obtain this information via tools like `mediainfo` Place the output in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and [edit] the link into your question. Thank you for helping us help you! You've provided some detail regarding the Nvidia card but nothing about the Radeon card. The output of `lshw -C display` for each respective card would be useful. Without further details I don't think anyone will be able to write a comprehensive answer. a guess regarding compression is all I've got ATM

Comment: @ElderGeek thanks for your attention. This happens for every video, even if streaming from YouTube. The Radeon card is not on my machine. I replaced it with this one. I said when the Radeon card was used, the videos were played smoothly, though I have not changed anything from the transition from Radeon to Nvidia. The same machine, the same Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Any details regarding the Radeon card?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more details, like what application exactly is playing the video (VLC, MPlayer, etc...) and how exactly is the "pixelated" pattern. Maybe by pixelated you mean teared? This uses to involve some problem with vertical syncing. Some screenshot would be helpfully.

As a quick test, could you run (install prime if you see command not found):

```
sudo prime-select query
```

If Nvidia GPU is the default, you should see "nvidia" as output. If the system is using by default some integrated graphic card, you'll see "intel". You could force it to use the discrete card by:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Comment: The output is `nvidia` because there is only one GPU. I replaced the Radeon GPU with Nvidia. The problem is exactly the same in all players. No, the image is not `teared`, it is not that visible. The transition between frames is not smooth. It's like when the system is out of memory, but I have 64GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Without further details on the Radeon card, it's likely impossible to provide an exact answer to your question. Be that as it may, here's some likely culprits.

Differences in the encoders used for [nvidia cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC) and [Radeon cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Coding_Engine) could feasibly result in differences in performance. Specifically based on what you stated about "fast movement in a video" indicates a feature called [motion blur.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur)

As far as a solution to the problem is concerned you may get better results with the latest driver which ATM is 418.56 currently available [here.](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us)

If you are using DisplayPort for connectivity, [the Nvidia implementation has been reported to have issues](https://www.techpowerup.com/244981/nvidia-has-a-displayport-problem-which-only-a-bios-update-can-fix) and might not be as good as [AMD's implementation.](https://www.displayport.org/pr/amd-radeon-hd-6000-series-first-to-achieve-displayport-1-2-source-certification/)

Here's a listing of [Displayport certified components from VESA.](https://vesa.org/displayport-developer/certified-components/)